# Convert Curl command into Java/Android

Tags: java, api, curl, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am developing two applications -

First one is web application using Spring MVC 3

And the second one is an Android application for same web application.

In both, I am integrating basic authentication to authenticate user on that site using the APIs.

In the API tutorial, following curl command is given to authenticate user -

**$ curl -u username:password insert_Url_here -d '[xml body here]'**

I am not getting, how to convert this command in Java and android code.

Please guide me. I am totally stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HttpClient 4, you will need to do the following:

- create the client:

> CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

- create the POST Request:

> final HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(SAMPLE_URL);

- set the body of your POST request:

> request.setEntity(new StringEntity("the body of the POST"));

- configure authentication (presumably Basic Auth):

> UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
>
> postRequest.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request, null));

That's it - this is essentially what your `curl` command does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen. This is working fine for me. But authenticate method (new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request, null)) is deprecated. Can you provide any other approach too ?

Comment: Did you copy the line exactly as it is now (including the last null argument)? I'm using the latest httpclient version (4.3.1) and it is not deprecated - it's likely that you didn't include the last argument.