# cURL command in Android app

Tags: android, json, curl

I want to run a cURL command into my android application but I don't know how.
This is the example command:

```
curl --data "mail=abc@abc.com&pass=azerty" http://www.website.com/login/
```

Comment: You're looking for an HTTP client.

Comment: I don't find how to do that with CURL call

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782140/convert-curl-command-into-java-android

Comment: @GhassenKhelif: No; you need to send an HTTP request using an HTTP client in your language.

Comment: @SLaks: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using android NDK, [here](http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.com/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html) is a nice article to achive this task

Comment: Thank you for your help but i found this solution much complicated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all I found this solution :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://wwwebsite.com/login/");
                String HTML = "";
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            3);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail","abc@abc.tn"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "azerty"));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    if (response.getEntity() != null) {
                        Log.i("RESPONSE", HTML.toString());
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e("ee","ee");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ee","ee");

                }

            }
        }).start();
```